# Activate jmxmp in jconsole

Tags: java, jvm, jmx, jconsole, jvm-arguments

I am trying to connect to my tomcat server with jconsole via jmxmp protocol. I put `jmxremote_optional.jar` everywhere in jdk and jre folders, but when I try to connect I still get:

```
malformed exception: unsupported protocol
```

How can I enable this protocol?  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to make sure that the JVM arguments have JMX enabled.   The following arguments to the JVM are required:

```
java \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
    ...
```

Here's a page on how to [enable JMX using Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/monitoring.html).

---

**Edit:**

I believe that ultimately, this was a classpath issue.  Here's a page which gives some examples about [how to set the classpath when running jconsole](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13729/accesscust.htm).  It is something like:

```
jconsole -J-Djava.class.path=$JAVA_HOME/lib/jconsole.jar:\
    $JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:\
    $WLS_HOME/lib/wljmxclient.jar \
    -J-Djmx.remote.protocol.provider.pkgs=weblogic.management.remote
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have done it. I feel, that something wrong with jconsole, because it does not connect and throw malformed exception: unsopported protocol

Comment: When do you ge the unsupported protocol error?  When you try to connect @EK?

Comment: Yes. I start jconsole like "jconsole -debug" and try to connect to service:jmx:jmxmp://localhost:9875. and get java.net.MalformedURLException: Unsupported protocol: jmxmp

Comment: Have you tried to configure the classpath for jconsole?  Here's a page that gives some examples: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13729/accesscust.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link, but there is not anything about JMXMP. JMXrmi works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry, I showed that link because it shows how to set the classpath for jconsole.  Are you doing that @EK?

Comment: this is how I try to run jconsole -J-Djava.class.path=JAVA_HOME/lib/jconsole.jar:JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:JAVA_HOME/lib/jmxremote_optional-1.0_01-ea.jar Of course, jmxremote_optional-1.0_01-ea.jar is in folder. Thanks!

Comment: It throw me exception. Could not find main class. Program will exit

Comment: It should be $JAVA_HOME and you should be able to do a `ls $JAVA_HOME/lib/jconsole.jar` to see that file otherwise you'll need to maybe set the $JAVA_HOME env variable @EK.  Best of luck.

Comment: if I type jconsole and press enter, it works, that mean that $JAVA_HOME visible to jconsole